# Get a dropbox url from the command line

Tags: windows, dropbox

I'm a windows 7 user and I want to access an object from within my public dropbox folder using the command line.  How do I do that (note my skills with the command line are weak so be gentle please.  This is what I'm basing my information on: [DROPBOX CITE LINK](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/Using_Dropbox_CLI#PUBURL)

Here's the path to my drop box and what I attempted:

```
#the path
C:/Users/trinker/Dropbox/Public/plot.png

#the attempt to retrieve the url of plot.png
CD C:/Users/trinker/Dropbox/Public/
C:/Users/trinker/Dropbox/bin/dropbox.py puburl C:/Users/trinker/Dropbox/Public/plot.png
```

Note my slashes are going the opposite way you'd normally see them on a windows machine as I'm using this within another program that requires the slashes be in this direction or doubled as in `\\`

The goal is to retrieve the url for the dropbox object.

Comment: and what's the outcome? this assumes you have Python installed and configured, and I suspect dropbox.py will need to be local, installed in some other directory on your machine.

Comment: I think I found a way around this problem just pasting together the url each time.  I did not realize that the number that's assigned in drop box is your account number and that is the same each time.

Comment: Jim I added the goal per your comment.  If this is doable on windows it would be nice because I want to share the code.

Comment: I think you're out of luck on Windows, at least with that specific script.  If you look at the code, there are checks to ensure it's running from a Linux box and "Platform not supported" is output otherwise. I'm not a dropbox dev, but follow this thread to the very bottom http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=23715 which leads to a dev API announcement implying programmatic access to the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a work around pointed out to me by my friend Dason.  Go to your public folder and copy the link from a file.  Here's one of mine:

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61803503/%20wordcloud.pdf
```

The account number is always the same for your own drop box.  So the following form will allow me to share documents:

```
file.path("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61803503", DOCUMENT_NAME_HERE)
```

Comment: Note, if it gives a link like `https://www.dropbox.com/s/owtezozxwzgd1xr/animated-background.html`, you can change the `www.dropbox` to `dl.dropboxusercontent` - e.g. `http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/owtezozxwzgd1xr/animated-background.html`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are doing but if that is the url to your dropbox share, and you just wanted to access via command line have you tried just mapping a network drive to that URL to see if it works?